# Invalid Argument 'if_exists='skip' for Airflow BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, invalid-argument

I am attempting to use the `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator` Airflow operator to check for the existence of a BigQuery table and to create the table with a given schema if it does not exist or move on to the next operator if it does exist.

My operator constructor reads:

```
check_and_create_table = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
        task_id='check_and_create_final_table',
        project_id = GCP_PROJECT,
        dataset_id = BQ_DATASET,
        table_id = BQ_TABLE,
        schema_fields=get_final_schema(),
        if_exists='skip'
    )
```

and according to the [airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator:%7E:text=originating%20account%20(templated).-,if_exists,-(str)%20%E2%80%93%20What), the `if_exists` parameter should be set to `'skip'` to achieve this. Unfortunately, I am receiving a DAG import error in Airflow which reads:

```
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 408, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 756, in __init__
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator (task_id: check_and_create_final_table). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'if_exists': 'skip'}
```

If anyone has any ideas, they would be much appreciated.

Comment: which version of airflow are you using ? i think its from 2.6 only and you should use exist_ok instead

Comment: 2.4.3, which would explain it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if_exists implemented in airflow version 2.6 and exist_ok depredated according that.

for version before 2.6 you should use exist_ok as an alternative

this is the [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/29394)